# In rubyonrails, how to get the associated model class from and ActiveRecord::Relation object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, classname, relation

Suppose I have an model:

```
class Post
end  

posts = Post.where(***)  
puts posts.class # => ActiveRecord::Relation
```

Then how can I get the model class name through the variable 'posts', maybe some method called model_class_name:
    puts posts.model_class_name # => Post

Thanks :)

Answer (score 22):

The #klass attribute of [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) returns the model class upon which the relation was built:

```
arel = User.where(name: "fred")
arel.klass    # User
```

To get the class's name:

```
arel.klass.name
```

This is known to work with these versions:

- Originally tested in ActiveRecord 4.2.4.
- Works in Rails 5.2 (@Raphael Souza)

Answer (score 6):

For a solution that works, even if there are no related items:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments
end

Post.reflect_on_association(:comments).klass
=> Comment
```

Comment: Doesn't work when using `options: { class_name: 'AnotherClass' }`

Answer (score 0):

The most simple and direct answer to your question is:

```
posts.first.class.name
```

Which is equivalent to writing:

```
posts.[0].class.name
```

You can do this because your query will return an enumerable result. (ActiveRecord::Relation implements Ruby's Enumerable interface).

-- Scott

Comment: Hey Croplio, 4 months have passed. Did this answer solve your problem?

Comment: If `posts` returns no rows, then `posts.first` will be nil and this won't work.