# How can I determine the original class for an ActiveRecord Relation without submitting the query to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Suppose I have several different models and I'm building up a complex relation by passing them to other classes like:

```
class UserDefinedParameter
  def apply(base_relation)
    base_relation.where(:abc => self.value)
    #I want to see if base_relation was a ModelA here
  end
end

class UserDefinedSort
  def apply(base_relation)
    base_relation.sort("#{self.col} DESC")
  end
end

[ModelA, ModelB].each do |m|
  result = m.where(:user => current_user)
  UserDefinedParameter.all {|udp| result = udp.apply(result)}
  UserDefinedSort.all {|uds| result = uds.apply(result)}
end
```

What if I need to know whether I have `ModelA` or `ModelB` inside one of the `apply` methods?  How could I determine this?

I can't do `base_relation.first.class` (like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263844/in-rubyonrails-how-to-get-the-associated-model-class-from-and-activerecordrela) because the query isn't fully formed and ready to go to the database yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`base_relation.klass` should do the trick without a database query.